# Parallax onclick menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm working on horizontal parallax. On my horizontal webpage, I have several div where I applied parallax effects on pictures. Actually, if I scroll with the horizontal scroll the parallax seems working. My problem, is when I click on the items menu the parallax seems not working.
Do you know what I should modify ?
Here is my fiddle : [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/jarod51/StZR4/)

My javascript test :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

       $("body").addClass("has-js");
        $("form").bind("submit",function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
        });
       $("#banner a").bind("click",function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           var target = $(this).attr("href");
           $("html, body").stop().animate({
               scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left,
               scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
           }, 1200);
       });
    });

$(function(){
    /* main background image. moves against the direction of scroll*/
    $('.panel').scrollParallax({
        'speed': -0.2
    });

    /* inner items, moves slightly faster than the background */
    $('.panel .inner').scrollParallax({
        'speed': -0.5
    });

    /* two additional samples inside item2, both moving with direction of scroll*/
    $('.panel .inner-lev1').scrollParallax({
        'speed': 0.2
    }); 
    $('.panel .inner-lev2').scrollParallax({
        'speed': 0.5
    });
});

$("#banner a").bind("click",function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           var target = $(this).attr("href");
$('.panel .inner-lev1').scrollParallax({
        'speed': 0.2
    });            
       });
```

Comment: Hi Zach, yeah it seems working when we scroll only with the scroll horizontal navigation but not when we click on menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a z-index on the navigation.

Something like this:

```
#banner {z-index: 10}
```

should do the trick.

Good luck!